# Working symlink isn't accessable through explorer Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, shortcuts, symbolic-link

I made a symlink to an folder with `mklink` on w8x64 between two NTFS partitions on the same disk. All programs think it's a valid folder, but Windows explorer doesn't seem to get this, and displays a shortcut symbol that can't be double clicked. If I click it a prompt appears asking for the correct program to open the file.

Is there some fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

The /D option does the trick...

**Long answer:** First open the cmd.exe with admistrator rights. Then type:

`mklink /D some-Name Path-to-Target-Directory`

The `/J` option which creates a junction might also be useful for SkyDrive and the like, because they don't follow normal symlinks correctly.

Comment: +1 for working it out. Could you please include the actual command that worked for you?